# How to input a NodeJS variable into an SQL query

Tags: sql, node.js, node-mysql

I want to write an SQL query that contains a NodeJS variable. When I do this, it gives me an error of 'undefined'.

I want the SQL query below to recognize the `flightNo` variable. How can a NodeJS variable be input into an SQL query? Does it need special characters around it like `$` or `?`.

```
app.get("/arrivals/:flightNo?", cors(), function(req,res){
var flightNo = req.params.flightNo;

connection.query("SELECT * FROM arrivals WHERE flight = 'flightNo'", function(err, rows, fields) {
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You will need to put the **value** of the variable into the SQL statement.

This is no good:

```
"SELECT * FROM arrivals WHERE flight = 'flightNo'"
```

This will work, but it is not safe from SQL injection attacks:

```
"SELECT * FROM arrivals WHERE flight = '" + flightNo + "'"
```

To be safe from SQL injection, you can escape your value like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM arrivals WHERE flight = '" + connection.escape(flightNo) + "'"
```

But the best way is with parameter substitution:

```
app.get("/arrivals/:flightNo", cors(), function(req, res) {
  var flightNo = req.params.flightNo;

  var sql = "SELECT * FROM arrivals WHERE flight = ?";
  connection.query(sql, flightNo, function(err, rows, fields) {
  });
});
```

If you have multiple substitutions to make, use an array:

```
app.get("/arrivals/:flightNo", cors(), function(req, res) {
  var flightNo = req.params.flightNo;
  var minSize = req.query.minSize;

  var sql = "SELECT * FROM arrivals WHERE flight = ? AND size >= ?";
  connection.query(sql, [ flightNo, minSize ], function(err, rows, fields) {
  });
});
```

Comment: Should I use connection.escape even when I want to use "INSERT INTO table" command ?

So it should be like this:  "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('" + connection.escape(flightNo) + "'")"

Comment: You should protect against SQL injection with every query. Better to use `connection.query('INSERT INTO table VALUES (?)', flightNo, function(err, result) { });`

Comment: This is how am doing it:

    var sql = "INSERT INTO admins VALUES(null, '" + adminUser +"', '" + 
    adminPass + "', '" + adminName + "' , '"+ adminSurname +"') ";
        con.query(sql,function(error, rows, fields){
            if(!!error) {
                console.log('Query Failed' + error.message);
            } else {
                console.log('Query Successful');
                console.log(rows.insertId);
                next();
            }
        });

Comment: @ChristosMichael You should be escaping those values. I'd do it with parameter substitution: https://codeshare.io/2WbdvY

Comment: IBM_DB requires the parameters be an array even if there's only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

From ES6 you can use template literals with `${expression}`.

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are [literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#literals) delimited with backtick (`) characters, allowing multi-line strings and interpolation with expressions.

Use like this:

```
connection.query(`
SELECT * 
FROM arrivals 
WHERE flight = ${flightNo}
`, //rest of your code
```