# How would add a messages sent to my sql database

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

here is what I have so far

```
con.query(`SELECT * FROM messages WHERE guildID = ${message.guild.id} AND username = ${message.author.username}; `)
    con.query(`SET messagesSent = messagesSent + 1;`)
```

how would I add 1 to messages sent when the user sends a message under that username and guild id?

Comment: With an [UPDATE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html): `UPDATE messages SET messagesSent = messagesSent + 1 WHERE guildID = ${message.guild.id} AND username = ${message.author.username};` That being said, instead of concatenating your sql string together, instead use parameters to bind your `message.guild.id` and `message.author.username` into your sql. This will insure you don't suffer a SQL injection attack should someone manage to make their `message.author.username` something like `1;drop table messages;--`

Comment: @JNevill this is the error I get Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'Jerry' in 'where clause'

Comment: You'll need single quotes around your the string literal in your sql. So `UPDATE messages SET messagesSent = messagesSent + 1 WHERE guildID = ${message.guild.id} AND username = '${message.author.username}';` Again, consider [binding parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168942/how-to-input-a-nodejs-variable-into-an-sql-query) to avoid this. The last example shared by the top answer there is an example of this using the `?` character in the sql.

Comment: @JNevill ok so how would I call it? like to a user info command?