# website timeout after adding a .inv to req,session

Tags: node.js, express, session

I am trying to add a unique ID to my `req.session` but when the function executes if I want to go to another page it timeout due to infinite loading. Is there a way to do this correctly?

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.query.inv) {
        sql.query(`SELECT * FROM inv WHERE inv='${req.query.inv}';`, (error, result) => {
            if(error) console.log(error);
            if(result.length < 1) {
                req.session.inv= '';
                next()
            } else {
                req.session.inv = `?inv=${req.query.inv}`;
                console.log(req.session.inv);
                next()
            }
        });
    } else {
        if(!req.session.inv) {
            req.session.inv= '';
            next()
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a middleware which must call `next()` when complete so that the next middleware in the stack can be called. See Express's [Using middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application) documentation.

Take a look at your logic - if `inv` is not in your query string but does exist in your session, then `next()` is never called. This aligns with the issue you are having - you add `inv` to your session, and then on your next page load you will be forever stuck in your middleware. You would instead want logic like this:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.query.inv) {
        /* .... */
    } else if (!req.session.inv) {
        req.session.inv= '';
    }

    next(); // this makes sure that next() always gets called
});
```

You also have a glaring [SQL Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) risk because you are taking a raw query string value and passing it directly into your query. What you want is a [parameterized query](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#Parameterized%20query) - I linked to node-postgres documentation even though I'm not sure what database you are actually using. As of now your query is **not** safe.

Comment: Thank you for your reply it worked for me, the only thing I am asking now is how can I make my SQL Query safe? PS. Using MySQL.

Comment: You can take a look at the answer here for help with that, it explains everything very well  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41172686/1307183